# How to change color of a material skin control in runtime C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, material-design

I am using the material skin theme in my windows form app in C#. I have inserted some `materialSingleLineTextField` with a blue accent color. 
When the user haven't insered all information and clicks on the `Print` button, all the required text fields should turn to red. 
How can I implement this? Also the text fields should stay focused.

I've tried to find something on Google but I can't find anything useful. Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Hello mate,

By coincidence or not, I have just reported this bug on their Github page.
Follow this issue and maybe you'll find your answer: https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin/issues/235